# Invalid Initializer in C String

Tags: arrays, c, compiler-errors, initialization, string-literals

I am testing out a uppercase to lowercase converter in C (I'm relatively new), and I've been having some issues in the main file (which I have attached below). I can add the upperlower.c code, but I don't think it's related to my problem. I am getting some invalid initializer errors, and I would've though this works. I have attached an image of the error message. You can also see in the code that I have commented out some strcpy methods, as they caused some runtime segmentation fault errors. Does anyone know what's going on?
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcmtB.png)

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "upperlower.h"

#define SAMPLESTRING "AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz"

int main()
{
    char* lower[] = SAMPLESTRING;
    char* upper[] = SAMPLESTRING;

    // strcpy(*lower, SAMPLESTRING);
    // strcpy(*upper, SAMPLESTRING);

    ToLower(lower, lower);
    ToUpper(upper, upper);

    printf("Lower: %s\nUpper: %s\n", lower, upper);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 14 **An array of character type may be initialized by a character
> string literal** or UTF−8 string literal, **optionally enclosed in
> braces**. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the
> terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of
> unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

That is you could declare a character array and initialize it with a string literal like

```
char lower[] = SAMPLESTRING;
```

However you declared an array of pointers of the type `char *` instead of a character array. In this case you need to enclose the initializer in braces like

```
char* lower[] = { SAMPLESTRING };
```

In the line above there is declared an array with one element of the pointer type `char *` that points to the first character of the string literal `SAMPLESTRING`. However using the pointer (the single element of the array) you may not change the string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

Taking into account this call of `printf`

```
printf("Lower: %s\nUpper: %s\n", lower, upper);
```

where there is used the format string `"%s"` it seems you are going to deal exactly with character arrays. Otherwise you had ro write

```
printf("Lower: %s\nUpper: %s\n", lower[0], upper[0]);
```

So you need to write

```
char lower[] = SAMPLESTRING;
char upper[] = SAMPLESTRING;
```

or

```
char lower[] = { SAMPLESTRING };
char upper[] = { SAMPLESTRING };
```

instead of

```
char* lower[] = SAMPLESTRING;
char* upper[] = SAMPLESTRING;
```

In this case calls of `strcpy` will look like

```
strcpy( lower, SAMPLESTRING);
strcpy( upper, SAMPLESTRING);
```

though the arrays already contain this string literal due to their initializations.

Answer (score 3):

Typing `char * lower[N];`, you ask your compiler to create a pointer on a character array.

But you want just a characters array:

```
char lower[] = SAMPLESTRING;
char upper[] = SAMPLESTRING;
```

Answer (score -1):

The part you may be confused about is using a global constant as the value for the character array.

Setting the value using a gobal constant is equivalent to setting the value using a local variable, string, or character array.

Any of these methods should be sufficient:

```
char array[] = globalvariable;
char array[] = localvariable;
char array[] = "this is a string";
char array[] = {'t','h','i','s',' ','i','s',' ','a',' ','s','t','r','i','n','g'}
```

if you intend on using a pointer, then your array variable used to point towards the array does not need to be an array just a pointer.

Using your code, this would be performed like this:

```
char * lower;
char * upper;
```

Comment: C 2018 6.7.9 paragraphs 14-16 specify that an array should be initialized with an appropriate string or a brace-enclosed list of initializers. Using a bare `globalvariable` or `localvariable` is inappropriate. The macro `SAMPLESTRING` defined in the question is not a global variable, nor is it a “global constant,” as there is no such thing in the C standard.

Comment: Where I see you your point global variable isn't an accurate term, according to [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/constants/create_define.php) website the term "global constant" is in fact correct. A global constant being a term where the value cannot be changed and is accessible by the entire program.

Comment: The page you link to does not contain the word “global”, and use that site’s search function to search for “global” does not produce any results relevant to C. Further, a macro defined in a `#define` directive is not accessible by the entire program; the effect of the directive is limited to the translation unit.

Comment: After further review you are somewhat correct. [This](https://www.tutorialandexample.com/define-in-c) reference states the scope of the macro is limited to the source file the macro is defined within. Therefore, anything within the file can access the macro.